# Parametrizando valor à ser Criptografado na Query SQL

Tags: java, sql, web-service

Atualmente, a query de consulta que retorna resultados é a seguinte:

```
 SELECT nome, email, senha
 FROM Professor 
 WHERE email = ? AND senha = HASHBYTES('SHA1','" + senha + "') 

 p.setString(1, email);
```

Ao tentar parametrizar o valor dentro do recurso HASHBYTES (com o placeholder '?', no *PreparedStatement* do Java), há algum erro de leitura/tipo/conversão que faz com que a consulta não retorne resultados.

Qual seria a maneira correta de parametrizar esta Query, para depois ser feito o *binding* com o valor da variável *senha*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido com a conversão do tipo do valor parametrizado.

```
select email, password
from Professor
where email = ?
and senha = hashbytes('sha1', convert(varchar, ?))
```

Mais detalhes sobre a diferença na criptografia de Varchar ou NVarchar em [SQL Server sha1 value in prepared statement gives a different value than hardcoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846256/sql-server-sha1-value-in-prepared-statement-gives-a-different-value-than-hardcod)